# what should be HTTP status code for credentials Expired error/exception?

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

I am developing RESTful APIs, I have implemented token-based authentication, where token digest is prepared using time-stamp. Now when request comes to API server, I am checking if the supplied time-stamp is invalid ( i.e. date-time from future/past is specified) then am throwing error message indicating that "future token detected" or "token has expired". I need to attach HTTP status code I am confused about which status code is suitable for this situation?

I have gone through the status codes available ([ref1](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html), [ref2](http://robertlathanh.com/2012/06/http-status-codes-401-unauthorized-and-403-forbidden-for-authentication-and-authorization-and-oauth/)) so far, I think, using 400 'bad request' will be suitable here instead of 401 'Unauthorized' and 403 'forbidden'  status codes.

what do you think guys?

Comment: As for me 401 is slightly more suitable here

Comment: doesn't 401 mean credentials are valid but is not authorized to access the resource ( e.g. normal user trying to access admin specific API)

Comment: Have read your ref1/ref2. 403 confuses me as potential consumer of your api. According to it: "Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.". So I reauthorization shouldn't help me.
And 400 is just general error which cover the details. Than You have to add specific message/header which is not the best choice

Comment: yes I did read them before posting questions here, uncertainty about 401/403 for the mentioned scenario lead me to go with 400 bad reques which I am not sure is still best choice, so yes I am looking for information  which code is more suitable here and how

Comment: Well at the end its up to you. :)
In all our cases we use 401 as an signal that we (again) want to receive credentials.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the timestamp is invalid, I think the token is invalid. So the client is not authenticated anymore. So I would throw a 401 Unauthorized. You're free to add extra data of the context as HTTP header with the X- prefix, or to add a response body encoded according to the Accept request header (json, text, etc.). Like:

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "details": {
      "code": "401.3",
      "description": "The timestamp provided must not be in the future."
    }
  }
}
```

It is not a 403 Forbidden : 403 means "the client is authenticated but does not have the right to send this request". In your case, I think the client is not authenticated any more.

Answer (score 0):

Works Around... Thinking about expired password (not exactly expired credencial)
I found this from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
403 Forbidden
The client does not have access rights to the content; that is, it is unauthorized,
so the server is refusing to give the requested resource.
Unlike 401, the client's identity is known to the server.
//- - - -
Well I think the better is response with 403 with description or custom content header, and so the client need to call the endpoint with your auth + param with new password.

Now, about expired credencial (yet thinking about user and password, not token), 403 I think good too, because "the client's identity is known to the server" but unauthorized.

About token and your timestamp, 401 with description is good I think, because one of first steps is the server see the timestamp, and the timestamp will fail before checking any credentials..