# Force a password change over RESTful API

Tags: rest, restful-authentication

I've a RESTful API in which i want to implement a way to tell the client, that the password of the authorized user is expired and has to be set first before the client is allowed to use the API.

At the moment i return a 201 with a token inside like this
`{"rows":["tokenxyz"]}` on POST /login.  I imagine a rebuild to return 201 `{"rows":[{"token":"xyz", "expire_ts":"2017-30-28 07:54:21", "password_change_needed":1}]}`. After that i would return 403 FORBIDDEN on every request despite the patch request on the users password.

I'm not really sure about this plan. Are there better ways to respond on REST requests but tell the client, he has to change the password? I'm looking for best practices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the good http status code to return on expired password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669508/whats-the-good-http-status-code-to-return-on-expired-password)

Answer (score 2):

Best practice would be to return "401 unauthorized". You are no longer authorized if your token expired or you need to change your password. 403 is only applicable if authentication was successful.

[What's the good http status code to return on expired password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669508/whats-the-good-http-status-code-to-return-on-expired-password)

[what should be HTTP status code for credentials Expired error/exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078459/what-should-be-http-status-code-for-credentials-expired-error-exception)

Comment: A 401 on a login seems wrong to me because the given credentials are valid. Only the admin ask me to set a new password first. As i return a 401 on login it would mean that i'm not allowed to authorize me - or am i wrong with this?

Comment: @MIB ah I was thinking about posting further requests to something other than /login

Comment: @MIB Returning 403 should be fine. However I would not allow this first request to return 201 if the password already was expired.

Comment: Okay i see your point, 201 would indicate everything is correct. As far as i read the given informations, a possible way could be a response including a special "update password" errorcode in the body. The status code could be 400. After receiving this the client has to send the current credentials plus the new password on /login to gain access.